# Next.js showing 404 page not found for other routes

Tags: next.js

Here is my config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
pageExtensions: ["jsx", "js"],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

My `page.j`s is the index page which is coming on the  "/" route.
I created another page, `blog.js` inside the same folder (please check the below screenshot).

When I go to http://localhost:3000/blog it is showing a 404 page not found.

Please check what can be the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the route `/blog`, you would create a directory named `blog` within the `pages` directory. Inside the `blog` directory, you would create a file named `page.js` . This file will handle the `/blog` route specifically.

```
app
└── pages
    ├── page.js            // Handles the / route
    └── blog
        ├── page.js        // Handles the /blog route
        └── [slug].js       // Handles individual blog post pages, e.g., /blog/my-first-post
```

Answer (score 1):

[`app` and `pages` folders have a special meaning in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure). Do not nest the two as you did. You choose which one you want while creating your project with the last question:

[image]

Since you have the `app` with `page.js`, you have chosen `Yes` to the last question in the above image. And so, to have a `/about` route, you need to create a folder named `about` in `app` with a `page.js` in it, leading to `app/about/page.js`.

That's because, in the `pages` folder, the initial way of setting up routes, a file creates a route, but in the `app` directory, a route is created by a folder and a `page.js` is used to render that route, as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) shows it:

[image]

Finally, if you are following along a tutorial and want to use the `pages` router, the easiest way is to create a new project and answer the CLI accordingly:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```